# Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page - from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2017

I am trying to read a stored procedure and then output that to a flat file in SSIS.

[image]

and to the flat file

[image]

It is erroring on the field 'Name' and the file output stops before

'Men[']s Fairisle Jumper - L'

Any help appreciated. The apostrophe seems a strange character

Comment: The result sets definition uses `nvarchar` on all columns. Have you tried using `DT_NTEXT` instead of `DT_TEXT` for `Name`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Still fails changing it to DT_NTEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by making it

Unicode string [DT_WSTR]